# Value based on largest value by neighbouring column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Using `group_by()` I want to get the value of column `value` based on the largest value of column `value2`:

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                value = c(4,5,1,3,1,2,3,1),
                value2 = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"))

df %>% group_by(id) %>%
   sumarise(value2_of_largest_value = f(value, value2))

1  b
2  g
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(value2 = value2[which.max(value)])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `which.max` to get the index of the `value` and use that to subset the `value2`

```
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(x, y) y[which.max(x)]
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(value2 = f1(value, value2))
   #or simply
   # summarise(value2 = value2[which.max(value)]) 
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id value2
#  <dbl> <fct> 
#1     1 b     
#2     2 g
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach in `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

 df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(value == max(value))
```

or in `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[setDT(df1)[, .I[value == max(value)], by=id]$V1]
```